# Unable to add new iOS device for development in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying for more than 3 hour.  I am using the same Macbook and Xcode. Nothing new. But when I tried to add new device for a development.  The xcode organizer prompt. And I clicked on add this device for development. Everything went well.  That new ios device appear in my list in organizer.  I add a new provision profile.

But I cannot build . It shows the warning that "Valid signing identity is not found"

I know this warning message was asked severalt time. But my case is different. I didn't migrate to new macbook. This is the same one that I can build & run in the old ios device.

Somebody please help

Comment: make sure you have added the device(in iOS provisioning portal) and install the latest provisioning profile

Comment: check bundle identifier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is I could not sign the private key to the certificates. Because I have many private keys listed in the Keychain Access which were created by xcode ,I guess.

The solution is I deleted all private keys and create a new one. Manual update to Apple Developer section again and create new certificate and then add new certificate to a provisioning profile for new device .  Xcode automatic process causes a lot of trouble. The manual process might take more time but it is easier to spot a problem and fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be not in the device, but in the provisioning profile for your app.

I've had the same problem and it turns out that I haven't signed my app with an appropriate provisioning profile. The other thing that may happen is the fact that you have to download a new provisioning profile from [iOS developer portal](https://developer.apple.com) with the new device **added** to thу corresponding profile of your app - nothing difficult. Then just delete the old profile from the organizer and just after that open a new one - the app will be signed with it and run OK on the new device you've just added to the profile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have already done that twice.But the problem still persist. I have no clue how to solve this. It always said "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" when I build the code.

Comment: I just found the solution . I cleaned up all certificate and create new private key. It turns out to work . Xcode genarate many privatekeys with same name and also certification . I just remove it all in Keychain Access

Comment: @KongHantrakool great! This is a nice way out)